# "ITMS-90853: Invalid font" on TestFlight external testing

Tags: ios, ios14, xcode12

I have uploaded build with Xcode 12 - iOS 14. I am getting following error in the TestFlight external testing.

*Note: Build is working fine in internal testing.*

> App Store Connect   Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for
> TestFlight review for your app, "XYZ" 1.0 (1.0.1). Please correct the
> following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font
> named '' at 'XYZ.app/NORMAN.TTF'. Font basic parsability.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font
> named '' at 'XYZ.app/FancyPants.ttf'. Font basic parsability.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font
> named '' at 'XYZ.app/Alakob.ttf'. Font basic parsability.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font
> named '' at 'XYZ.app/AlternateGothicEF-NoTwo_0.ttf'. Font basic
> parsability.
>
> ITMS-90853: Invalid font - There was an error validating the font at
> 'XYZ.app/GothamRounded-Bold.ttf'. Font not supported by platform.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I also found this apple forum [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657598) but there is no solution provided.

Anyone have the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it looks like iOS still only supports `ttf`/`otf` family of fonts and DOES NOT support `woff` family of fonts. Valid in June 2021 still.

Even if you're shipping a Hybrid app (like Cordova / Capacitor / Ionic thing) and WKWebView perfectly supports `woff2` since forever - you'll still get `ITMS-90853: Invalid font` errors from "App Store Connect" Cerberus.

Comment: We're seeing this same thing as of August 2023.

Answer (score 0):

This is font validation errors. But these are coming after the iOS 14 - Xcode 12 update!

*I have fixed the fonts by using following software as suggested in this [article](https://www.iwebss.com/tech/540-fixing-fonts-with-validation-errors-on-mac)*

– Download and install CR8 Software Solutions free font editor for Mac called Type from here:
[Type light](https://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html)

– Open your problem ttf or otf font in the editor (choose File then Open).

– Choose Font then Rename Font then click RENAME button (without making any changes).

– Save your font (choose File then Save As).

– Done!

Re-upload the iOS build after updating this font...